# Stuck on finding the canonical form an endomorphism.

Tags: linear-algebra, jordan-normal-form

When asked to find the Jordan form of an endomorphism I'm usually given a matrix associated with the endomorphism from which I can compute the Jordan, yet this isn't the case with this excercise; instead I'm asked to find the Jordan form of an endomorphism $f$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ that has the following properties:

1. $e_2$ is an eigenvector with eigenvalue $\lambda$.
2. $e_3$ is an eigenvector with eigen value $\mu$.
3. $x_3=0$ is a $2$-cyclic subspace for some eigenvalue.
4. $f(1,1,1)=(2,1,1)$ or, equivalentely, $f(e_1+e_2+e_3)=2e_1+e_2+e_3$.

I'm quite stuck and would appreciate some help.

Comment: I’d start from $2e_1+e_2+e_3=f(e_1)+\lambda e_2+\mu e_3$

Comment: @egreg I see, although I'm not sure how to construct the matrix on canonical basis based on that.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the given information, the matrix with respect to the canonical basis can be computed from
$$
f(e_1)+\lambda e_2+\mu e_3=2e_1+e_2+e_3, \quad f(e_2)=\lambda e_2, \quad f(e_3)=\mu e_3
$$
whence the matrix is
\begin{bmatrix}
2 & 0 & 0 \\
1-\lambda & \lambda & 0 \\
1-\mu & 0 & \mu
\end{bmatrix}

Now you can apply the information you have about the subspace spanned by $e_1$ and $e_2$.

Comment: Wouldn't this force $\lambda =1$ and $\mu = 1$ so that the matrix becomes $\begin{pmatrix} 
2 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}$? I'm just somewhat confused because apparently I should be getting a different matrix.

Comment: @Leo Surely $\mu=1$. Why should $\lambda=1$?

Comment: Oh wait, it's $\lambda =2$, right?